# Why the unit of file system read-modify-write cycle is page size?

Tags: linux, filesystems

In my understanding, even if i want to overwrite a byte in middle of a file, OS and/or disk will read the content of **the size of page**, modify one byte and then write the contents back.

The page is a memory concept. Why file system use it as the unit of read-modify-write cycle?